# Is there reporting tool that Supports the click event on the field in the report viewer

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, report

I use Crystal Report and I have a problem. When I view the report and click on a particular field I can know which field was clicked or interacted, is there a way to get to the click event, I searched a lot but I could not find any solution, so is there anything else other than Crystal Report can do?
Example (when click on SaleID field on report >> open the SaleForm whith information of this SaleID)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, see if simply setting a hyperlink property solves your use case. 
Here's an image of the hyperlink proeprties dialog in Crystal Designer: 
https://www.screencast.com/t/pzTmCCU7mbWv

If that option doesn't do the trick for you, one of the 3rd-party Crystal Reports viewers listed [here](http://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#viewers) allows a double-click to launch another report or another application and pass parameters to it.

Comment: i have a constructor in SaleForm (string txtSaleid)
what should i type in hyperlink to open SaleForm with Saleid parameter 
give me example pls